# Express Migration Tool Archived Items

Tags: upgrade, migration

I'm upgrading a site from Sitecore 6.5 SP2 to Sitecore 8.2 Update 4.  When running the Express Migration Tool (version 2.0) it isn't migrating over archived items.  I've tried doing a SQL insert to move the data from the Archive, ArchivedFields, and ArchivedItems tables.  While that does make the items show up in the Archive screen the items are not recoverable.  There are no errors in the log when trying to recover.  Just an audit entry.

AUDIT (sitecore\lyle): Restore: archive: archive, id: 8f08168e-095d-4d2f-9d56-ea0233c19b93

The item doesn't show up back in the main tree and remains as an entry in the archive table.

Has anyone successfully migrated the Archived Items?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sitecore support has filed a feature request to have the Express Migration Tool move data from the archives.

In the meantime running a SQL query to get the data over works.  You will need to get to Sitecore 6.6 Initial before executing the query as a new table was added to support the Archives.  The lack of the data from this fourth table was the issue with my query attempts.

Here is the SQL the ultimately worked.

```
USE sc820u4_master;

INSERT INTO dbo.Archive (ArchivalId, ItemId, ParentId, Name, OriginalLocation, ArchiveDate, ArchivedBy, ArchiveName)
SELECT ArchivalId, ItemId, ParentId, Name, OriginalLocation, ArchiveDate, ArchivedBy, ArchiveName 
FROM sc660u0_master.dbo.Archive;

INSERT INTO dbo.ArchivedFields (RowId, ArchivalId, VersionId, FieldId, Value, Created, Updated)
SELECT RowId, ArchivalId, VersionId, FieldId, Value, Created, Updated
FROM sc660u0_master.dbo.ArchivedFields;

INSERT INTO dbo.ArchivedItems (RowId, ArchivalId, ItemId, Name, TemplateID, MasterID, ParentID, Created, Updated)
SELECT RowId, ArchivalId, ItemId, Name, TemplateID, MasterID, ParentID, Created, Updated 
FROM sc660u0_master.dbo.ArchivedItems;

INSERT INTO dbo.ArchivedVersions (VersionId, ArchivalId, ItemId, dbo.ArchivedVersions.Language, dbo.ArchivedVersions.Version, ArchivedDate, ArchivedBy)
SELECT VersionId, ArchivalId, ItemId, Language, Version, ArchivedDate, ArchivedBy
FROM sc660u0_master.dbo.ArchivedVersions;
```